# Request library is not sending request

Tags: python, php

If I send second request by hand, it works fine, but if I try to do that by python, it is failing. No errors in apache log. File remains the same and is not overwritten.
Code:

```
def fen_actions(mode,fen):
    global url

    if mode: # 1-> Read 2-> Write
        params = {'mode':'readFen'}
    else:
        params = {'mode':'putFen','fen':fen}

    r = requests.get(url,params)
    return r.text

fen_actions(2,chess.STARTING_BOARD_FEN) #This is not working. Starting fen is just a string
temp_readed_fen = fen_actions(1,0) # This works
```

php code:

```
<?php


$f = fopen("tempfen.txt","r+") or die("Unable to open a file");

if (strval($_GET["mode"]) === strval("putFen"))
{
    if(strval($_GET['fen']) != strval(fread($f,filesize("tempfen.txt"))))
    {
        file_put_contents("tempfen.txt","");
        fwrite($f,$_GET['fen']);
    }

}

else if ($_GET["mode"] === strval("readFen"))
{
    echo(fread($f,filesize("tempfen.txt")));
}

ini_set('display_errors',1);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think your if statements aren't actually checking what you want. According to your comment, it should be:

```py
if mode == 1: # 1-> Read 2-> Write
    params = {'mode':'readFen'}
elif mode == 2: 
    params = {'mode':'putFen','fen':fen}
```